# Why are some of my files not available in the installation of my python module packaged using setuptools?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, setuptools, distutils

So I have made a small application that I typically want to package and share it with the world. I read the tutorials for packaging my app using setuptools. It was going well until I got stuck at one place.

My directory structure is something like this:

```
- MyApp
  - setup.py
  - README.md
  - LICENSE.txt
  - MANIFEST.in
  - myapp
    - __init__.py
    - index.py
    - utils
      - __init__.py
      - helper.py
      - some_dump.pickle
      - images
        - folder_1
          - image_1.jpg
          - image_2.jpg
        - folder_2
          - another_image_1.jpg
          - another_image_2.jpg
      - sounds
        - sound_1.wav
        - sound_2.wav
```

Given this directory structure, I have created the `setup.py` file with the `packages` option as the list containing `myapp` and `myapp.utils`. I have also created a `MANIFEST.in` file that will have all the files that I want to package but which are not included by default. Here is the content of the manifest file:

```
include README.md
include LICENSE.txt
include myapp/utils/*.pickle
include myapp/utils/sounds/*.wav
include myapp/utils/images/folder_1/*.jpg
include myapp/utils/images/folder_2/*.jpg
```

The problem is that all these files are created as required in the distribution package (.zip), but when I try to use the distribution package to try the install the package myself, I don't see the images, sounds or the pickle file.
i.e. when I run `python setup.py install`, I don't see these files in the `build/lib` folder. I am not sure what the reason is. Could anyone help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you have several different questions (e.g. one about installing resource files, and one about installing PyQt from PyPi). Please split them to separate StackOverflow questions.

Comment: @pts: Generally, that's right, but the OP is asking if these two questions have a common root cause in a packaging issue.

Comment: The second is probably not the cause of the first. Meanwhile, you normally do not install non-code files in the middle of a package; use the resource files API instead. However, IIRC (it's been a while), PyQt has its own resource-files API instead of the one in `setuptools`/`pkg_resources`, and you might want to use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manifest is about distribution, not about installation.
You need to specify in `setup.py` what to install and WHERE:

```
setup(...,
  data_files=[(whereto1, [file1, file2]),
              (whereto2, [file3])]
 )
```

See http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files